# Angular HttpClient: How to read stream response part by part without waiting for full result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

So I am trying to read the Chat GPT API response from my NodeJS server. The response is piped from my backend to the client (in Angular).

```
const chatStream = await fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    model: process.env.CHAT_GPT_MODEL,
    messages,
    n: 1,
    max_tokens: parseInt(process.env.CHAT_GPT_TOKEN_LIMIT ?? "2000"),
    stream: true,
  }),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: "Bearer " + process.env.CHAT_GPT_API_KEY,
  },
});

res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
res.setHeader(
    "Content-Disposition",
    'attachment; filename="generated_text.txt"'
);

// Pipe the GPT API response directly to the client's response object
chatStream.body.pipe(res);
```

This is how I handle the response in my front end (Angular). This is my `httpPostStream` function:

```
  const res = this.http
    .post(this.getUrl(url), body, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        // eslint-disable-next-line quote-props
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.auth?.loginToken,
      },
      responseType: 'blob',
      observe: 'body'
    })
    .pipe(catchError(this.catchError.bind(this)));
```

And was called from this:

```
const res = this.http
  .httpPostStream('/create-new-chat-gpt-room', { title })
  .subscribe((result: any) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      const text = reader.result as string;
      const parts = text.split('\n'); // Split text into parts based on newline character
      for (const part of parts) {
        // Display each part as needed
        console.log(part);
      }
    };
    reader.readAsText(result);
  });
```

The problem is that `console.log(part)` only runs after the result is `fully` returned. I want to log each part as soon, as result, is returned part by part, I do not want to wait until the `Blob` is completed.

How can I do this?

Comment: use fetch: [Provide first class HTTP streaming API as part of @angular/commom/http package](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/44143)

Comment: @traynor is this still not supported using the FetchBackend maybe (https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHandler)?

Comment: Looks like it only works for responseType === 'text' (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/970d68fe764aec7319573c4a77f47bce9f468e58/packages/common/http/src/fetch.ts#L131)

Comment: @Juarrow good catch, I got some results with streaming text from the server, and with `{ observe: 'events', responseType: 'text', reportProgress:true }` settings

Comment: To use fetch with `provideHttpClient` you can do `provideHttpClient(withFetch())`.
If I get the whole thing working I will provide a full answer.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the normal `HttpClient` of Angular. You need the following approach to implement this.

In your `main.ts` where you have your `bootstrapApplication` call use `withFetch` to have HttpClient use the [HttpFetchBackend](https://angular.io/api/common/http/FetchBackend) so `fetch` is used for all HTTP requests.

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
    // ...
```

You can now use the HttpClient to do streaming responses, but you need to use these options:

```
{
  observe: "events",
  responseType: "text",
  reportProgress: true
}
```

You then get `HttpEvent`s in your response stream, which you can check the type of, and process.

```
export default class ChatComponent {
  currentUserMessage: string;
  chatMessages: ChatMessage[];
  loadingResponse: boolean = false;

  sendMessage() {
    if (this.currentUserMessage.trim() === "") return;

    this.loadingResponse = true;
    this.chatMessages.push({ role: "user", content: this.currentUserMessage});
    this.currentUserMessage= "";
    const responseMessage = {
      role: "assistant",
      content: "…",
    };
    this.chatMessages.push(responseMessage);

    this.http
      .post("/api/chat-gpt", this.chatMessages, {
        observe: "events",
        responseType: "text",
        reportProgress: true,
      })
      .subscribe({
        next: (event: HttpEvent<string>) => {
          if (event.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress) {
            responseMessage.content = (
              event as HttpDownloadProgressEvent
            ).partialText + "…";
          } else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
            responseMessage.content = event.body;
            this.loadingResponse = false;
          }
        },
        error: () => {
          this.loadingResponse = false;
        },
      });
  }
```

Comment: Mark, this will get the whole stream response in a single concatenated response instead of chunk by chunk response as we expect. The work is being done on that to get the individual chunk of response.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/52494

Comment: Correct the `partialText` contains the entire partial text of the message, instead of just a chunk. That is why my code does `responseMessage.content =` instead of `+=`.
For this usecase that is totally fine, and even easier / nicer to work with.

Comment: Yes, it would be fine for most of the scenarios, but here the OP is asking for getting the stream response directly and process it as soon as it gets started receiving on client instead of waiting for the whole response to get merged. That would be similar to normal API call for the clients. I hope Angular team merges that PR so that we can get the chunks in the download progress event. Anyway, it was a good example to process the streamed responses in same fashion as non-streamed responses.

Comment: Ahh, I think you misunderstand.
With this example it _does_ stream the response as it comes in.
The only difference is that the partial response that comes in via the `DownloadProgressEvent` is not a single chunk, but all chunks that have come in so far.

Comment: Ooh thank you so much for understanding and explaining it properly, I finally understood that part when I logged whole event on console to see what it was containing. If someone wants to show the output like ChatGPT then they would have to pluck the last chunk from the `partialText` and you can show the same effect as streaming responses.